# Enable backlight on ASUS ROG G551JX

Tags: dual-boot, asus, backlight

Recently dual booted UBUNTU 16.04 with pre installed windows 8.1 on my ASUS ROG G551JX. Backlight in the keyboard works perfectly when I log into widows but gets disabled as soon as I switch to UBUNTU, any idea how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Now I saw your post. You can write in terminal:

`echo 3 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness`

Which will activate the maximum brightness of the backlights. It can take values from 0 to 3, so when you want to decrease it, you can just change the 3 with any other value within that interval.

As a long term solution you could try making your own script with that piece of code and attribute it to specific key combinations by accessing your `Keyboard->Application Shortcuts` menu and setting there to run the script.

Have a nice day!